# Sparkle treats css files as routes

Tags: java, css, freemarker, spark-java

I'm using spark web framework for java with Freemarker template engine. I have my html code like this:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Custom styles for dashboard -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="dashboard.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-theme.min.css">
```

When I want to include these css files which are placed in my resources/public dir, Spark throws this:

```
[qtp765086197-18] INFO spark.http.matching.MatcherFilter - The requested route [/bootstrap-theme.min.css.map] has not been mapped in Spark for Accept: [null]
```

I don't know if it's an error, because everything is included fine, but how can I get rid of this?

Comment: You are not using the apache spark framework but the spark java framework. The first is a distributed computing engine for big data.

Comment: Oh, yeah, I realised that after few minutes, sorry

Answer (score 0):

The error clearly shows that the problem is with `.map` file.

**You have to add it to your folder, or instead, use the minified version of `bootstrap-theme`.**

Also, you can check with your browser if the css file is loading correctly using the Developer Tools.